# Proof: For every positive integer $n$, there is a sequence of $n$ consecutive positive integers containing no primes.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-factorization, proof-explanation

Let $x=(n+1)!+2$. I get how to prove that $x$ or $x+1$ is prime, but there is a step in my book that proves that $x+i$ is prime like this:

$x+i=(1)(2)(3)(4)....(n+1)+(i+2)$.

But then it factors out to this:

$x+i=(1)(2)(3)(i+1)(i+3)...(n+1)+1$.

How does $i+2$ factor out to this?

Comment: It doesn't. But $(x+i)/(i+2)$ does.

Comment: oops. I meant to ask how does (i+2) factor out, but I guess that doesn't either.

Comment: $x+i$ is NOT prime if $i+2\le n+1$ (because it's one of the factors of $(n+1)!$). So $x+i$ is not prime if $0 \le i \le n-1$.